# Rotate the view on one finger

Tags: android, gesture

i want to rotate the view in one finger at any angle depends upon user finger motion.user can rotate the view by dragging the finger around screen like gesture detector.Give me some times so i can start to work.it should work in one finger because i have implemented two fingers for zoom.

Comment: `double angle = Math.atan2(touchPos.y - view.y, touchPos.x - view.x);
   
   rotation = Math.toDegrees(angle) - 90;`

Comment: @MuhammadBabar on onfling ?

Comment: simple touch should accomplish that

Comment: @MuhammadBabar i have consumed touch and drag and drop and scale for gesture detetctor.so still woks?

Comment: Atleast give it a try

Answer (score 0):

function that handles rotation with one finger, the main idea is to calculate the centerX and centerY of your view and taking into consideration the status bar height if you using one.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {  

         switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    rotateX = event.getRawX();
                    rotateY = event.getRawY();

                    centerX = view.getX() + ((View) getParent()).getX() + (float) view.getWidth() / 2;

                    centerY = view.getY() + statusBarHeight + (float) view.getHeight() / 2;

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    newRotateX = event.getRawX();
                    newRotateY = event.getRawY();

                    double angle = Math.atan2(event.getRawY() - centerY, event.getRawX() - centerX) * 180 / Math.PI;

                    view.setRotation((float) angle - 45);

                    rotateX = newRotateX;
                    rotateY = newRotateY;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```